# Adding dots in a substring text description

Tags: php, html

I have this text description which i used a substring to limit to 400 characters. I would like to add some trailing dots in the end to indicate that there is more to the sentence. Is there a way to add said dots in the same echo?

```
echo substr('<br><p class="color-lighter-grey">'.$rowBlog['blog_description'].'</p>', 0, 400);
```

If I just add the dots at the end of the `</p>` it won't show because I assume it gets counted off the substring.

If I do an `echo '<p>.....</p>'` under the code, the dots will just go to another line.

How do I make them stay on the end of the substring?

[image: 1]

Comment: If you put the html tag inside the substr() , the function might cut the `</p>` part, put it out side the function and use concatination: `echo "<br><p class='color-lighter-grey'>" . subsrt($rowBlog['blog_description'], 0, 400) . "....</p>";`

Comment: What happens when your string is greater than 400 ?  The way you have it now you are including the html markup and not just the enclosed text.  Won't your trainling p tag get chopped off ?  You would be better off taking a substring of the $rowBlog and then enclosing that with the HTML tags.  If you did that you could even then just take a substring of 390 or whatever and append some trailing dot to that substring., although they might carry over to a new line in some cases.  You might want to look at a CSS also with ellipsis if that applies here somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the html from the database content and include the .... before the trailing `</p>`

```
echo "<br><p class="color-lighter-grey">";
echo substr($rowBlog['blog_description'], 0, 400);
echo strlen($rowBlog['blog_description']) > 400 ? "....</p>" : "</p>";
```

And, if the content is less than 400 chars don't display the dots

Answer (score 1):

First, using HTML code inside `substr` function may ended by destroying your code.
What I suggest to you is removing all HTML tags from string using `strip_tags` function then use `substr` function.

I use this function in my own project I hope it helps

```
 /**
 * @param   string  $str
 * @param   int     $allow_carc
 * @param   string  $placeholder
 */
 function substr_str($str,$allow_carc,$placeholder = '...') {
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    if(mb_strlen($str) > $allow_carc) {
        $substr = mb_substr($str,0,$allow_carc,"utf-8");
        return $substr.$placeholder;
    }else{
        return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Won't removing all the tags definitely break the html in the OPs case?

Comment: @John.M yes I knew that, but using substr with unknown string length that contain HTML code is not good at all. it always we'll throwing some parsing errors.
So what I suggested is changing the ways that he use to store data.

Comment: Yep, he needs to remove the html from the substr content first.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this worked but give it a try

```
echo substr("<br><p class='color-lighter-grey'> $rowBlog['blog_description']'...'</p>", 0, 400);
```